# Bolt read-only and/or hidden contenttypes

Tags: bolt-cms

Is it possible to have readonly or hidden contenttypes in Bolt?

For part of the website I'm building I use contenttypes to store information gathered from external sites (via an API), and user input (i.e. comments, replies, etc). The contenttype using the API theoretically should never need updating as the content pulled in is managed on the external site.

So is there a way to make them so they cannot be modified, or better yet not show them in the admin content list at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, no.

However what I do is to set the permissions on the 'resource' contenttypes to `developer` and that will hide them from users without that role.

Comment: Just to follow up, by 'hide', I mean in the backend, and by 'permisisons', I mean the edit permission for said contenttype :-)

Comment: Cool, had a feeling it would be a permission based solution.